# Can I use both ReadCommited and ReadCommitedSnapshot Transaction Isolation Levels in my c# app?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, transactions

Is there a way to use **ReadCommited** transaction isolation level for certain sql-queries while going with **ReadCommitedSnapshot** for others?

From what I know, all my transactions that were previously running under **ReadCommited IL**  will switch to **RCS** once I `SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON` for my database.

In `.NET` I only have `IsolationLevel.ReadCommited`.

And off course I can't just switch the `SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` on/off before each of my queries, because it requires  the very single sql-connection (and actually takes some time).

Are there any options?

Edit: Up!!!!!

Comment: If you're not getting the answers you want, it tends to indicate that you need to put more effort into your question and/or start a Bounty. It's rude to just keep editing your question to try to keep it prominent.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, ok, I got your point. I apologize for that. Going to do some investigation/experiments, and, probably answer it myself.

Answer (score 1):

At the SQL Server level, provided that `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` is `ON`, you can control it by using [`SET ISOLATION LEVEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) statements. **Don't** turn on `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`.

In that way, those connections that should have normal `RC` just run:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ_COMMITTED
```

(Or do nothing)

And for the connections where you want "`RCS`", run:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
If I turn on `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` and run `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT` that would result in transaction having **Snapshot** IL, not **RCS**, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ArturUdod - what feature(s) that distinguish RCS from SNAPSHOT are you trying to obtain?

Comment: From the remarks section of the Isolation Level page I've already linked to: "The transaction isolation levels define the type of locks acquired on **read** operations" (**My emphasis**)

Comment: I don't get the point, are you trying to persuade me to use snapshot over rcs? Well, I tend to this, but the question was whether ordinary RC is available to me if I turn on RCS.

Answer (score 0):

Use Snapshot isolation level, it actually maps to READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT here is msdn link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel.aspx

Comment: So, if my database has `SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON` and from my `c#` app I open a transaction with `IsolationLevel.ReadCommited` it will run it under ordinary **ReadCommited**? Actually can't see anything about this in your link

Comment: Each transaction can have its own isolation level regardless current database setting

Comment: Are trying to run nested transactions?

Comment: No, I want to be able to run one transaction as RC and second as RCS for the same database at the same time. Can do this in .net ?
Specify `RC` for 1st and `Snapshot` for second? Is there an article about this I can read?